# C# UML Class diagram

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, class

I'm writing a class diagram for my project, but unsure whether or not I should be including my overridden ToString() method on the diagram?

Also, how do I represent overridden methods on the diagram?

For example...

```
public override String SalesPrice()
```

Comment: Is this for a school project? If it is not - Simply autogenerate the diagram from your IDE for your doc, don't do that by hand (won't be used anyway). If it is - Ask your teacher whether he wants the overridden methods to be included or not, and follow his convention.

Comment: I didn't realise you could do that, thanks for pointing that out, I'll look it up, But yeah well I'm just trying to practise using UML diagrams, do you know how I would represent overridden methods on the diagram? Thanks for the reply

Comment: [uml 2.0](http://www.amazon.com/UML-2-0-Nutshell-In-OReilly/dp/0596007957) :: not sure if it is to old or whatever but I own it and it is pretty good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay so I finally found the book I mentioned (I am moving soon so it was packed).

in UML Inheritance is called generalization and it simply shows 2 boxes one pointing to the other no attributes.

I would assume that since you have defined the method in a base class that you would not have to in classes that inherit from it.

however there is a place that states that operations are defined as:

"*visibility* name ( *parameters* ) : *return-type* {*properties*}"

and for properties:

"*properties*

Specifies any parameters-related properties and is specified between curly braces. These are typically defined within the context of a specific model"

although the properties seem more for the parameters than the actual method but you may be able to fudge this a little

now for interfaces:

under the interfaces section it states explicitly that the class that "realizes" the interface must have it's own implementation. so in short I would add any overridden methods to the class diagram. otherwise whom ever implements your diagram might not realize that they need to override it.

I am using [uml 2.0 in a nut shell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007957) as my reference.  pg's 20,28,30

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me on that, So for the properties part on the end, is this where I would specify that it is an overridden method?

Comment: well, you can. I wouldn't call that breaking the rules but maybe bending them. I believe that section is for the parameters of the operation. but I feel it would be very readable to mark a overridden method in that area.

Comment: ok, thanks for that, I'll just do that for now, and then ask one of my tutors next week about it, Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Usually you wouldn't really need to include any extra details on the UML class diagram that the method is 'Overriden' or 'Virtual' Etc,

But if you wish to do so, I was told that it should be represented in the same way as abstract classes (Italic writting) / use of 'Arrows' either side like so..

```
<<Override>>
<<Virtual>>
```

So to comply with your example:

```
+ SalesPrice (): <<Override>> : String
```

and within your superclass you will need to specify as follows:

```
+ SalesPrice (): <Virtual>> : String
```